# which sensor is capable of tracking the emr

Tags: sensors

I read about applications like [tawkon](http://tawkon.com/) and [too close](https://greenswan.org/too-close/) recently. I am aware that they keep a watch to the mobile's radiation level and do something when the radiation level mounts. I am impressed with those apps. I wanna learn about how they work and I wish to code a simple app that keeps track of my phone's radiation level.

I thought that the **TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD** sensor would be able to find the radiation emission. When I browsed, I came to know that it is a sensor to measure the ambient geomagnetic field i.e; the magnetic field immediately surrounding the device.

I suspect that the radiations emitted out of the mobile phone must be largely responsible for the surrounding magnetic field. If what I think is right, I hope that I must be proceeding with the TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD sensor.

Please let me know, if I am right. If not, please guide me to the correct sensor that can achieve my own tawkon kinda.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not well fit here. "Which sensor" is rather an Android independent hardware question, and programming is another off-topic at this site – which deals with end-user questions toward Android.

Comment: The second app you linked seems to just use the proximity sensor.  The first one, I would guess, simply uses signal strength as an inversely-proportional metric (since your phone will need to amplify its own signal and thus "radiation" to reach a cell tower that is further away).

Comment: @MatthewRead: If that is the way 'tawkon' is programmed, will it not shout at us whenever we get complete signal strength?